# Listview: cannot resolve symbol 'setAdapter'

Tags: java, android

I have a problem on a project built up by Android Studio:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
dataAdapter = new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(MyActivity.this,R.layout.adapter_google_places_autocomplete)
  {
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    ...
  }

}
```

but 'setAdapter' appears in red and a popup message says

> Cannot resolve symbol 'setAdapter'

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: `setAdapter` expects a `ListAdapter`, which `dataAdapter` is not.

Comment: well, I declared it as GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter:

Comment: GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter dataAdapter = new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter

Comment: Which is a subclass of `ArrayAdapter`, not of `ListAdapter`

Comment: sorry but my Android Studio is very slow...ArrayAdapter

Comment: this is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350739/autocompletetextview-with-google-places-shown-in-listview-just-like-uber

Comment: I changed   public class "GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter"   in   "public class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ListAdapter", but the problem is not fixed

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the comments already, I am going to give you a suggestion, it might not be perfect since I am not amazing at Android just yet, perhaps instead of using a list view try and use a RecylerView.

I am not sure on your requirements but perhaps I can give you some insight and assist you in solving your problem. Let me try and show you some sample coding, that currently works for me, I am assuming you have everything set up for your adapter and so forth...

```
private List<ModelForItems> fireflyList = new ArrayList<>();
private MyAdapter sAdapter;

RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
sAdapter = new MyAdapter(fireflyList, this);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(sAdapter);
```

if there is anything you don't understand or if you need any further help please let me know. I hope I did not completely miss your point and am at least able to aid you in some way.

Comment: hi Rookie, thanks for your help; effectively i need your help to solve this problem, but it is a little difficult to communicate via this site, can I add you on gmail?

Comment: For sure, I will be happy to assist you as best I can, leave your email here, and I will send you a mail from my personal Gmail :)

Comment: bbilicu@yahoo.it