# Searching functionality with autocomplete address for google maps in my application

Tags: android

I am implementing my application , the requirement is I need to search locations in autocomplete textview while I typing in that view the list with those keywords has to bind to that text view and once I click on that text the location marker has to show the location on google map. please help me out

Comment: Check this ,this is actually what you look for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45107806/autocomplete-search-bar-in-google-maps

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look into below link :

1.https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete

2.[AutoCompleteTextView with Google Places shown in ListView just like Uber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350739/autocompletetextview-with-google-places-shown-in-listview-just-like-uber)

3.http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-places-api-autocomplete-getplacebyid/

4.https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-autocomplete-api-example/

Comment: Thank you for your response